# How can I enable ssh onTP-Link TD-W8961N?

Tags: router, ssh

I was trying to work on AAA (authentication authorization and accounting) project but my keep facing access denied (permission denied) issue. Telnet works, but how can I enable SSH on this router?

Comment: Please edit your post: Can you please add the exact SSH error messages? Perhaps even the output of the SSH command with `-vvv` add as a parameter. The SSH command would be something like `ssh -vvv 123.456.789.0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you get permission denied errors SSH is already enabled.
But the user-account you use to attempt to login doesn't have permission.

I'm not familiar with that particular router, but usually you need to configure somewhere in the router which accounts have permission for which of the various management interfaces.

(And please disable telnet asap. It is very insecure because it doesn't do any encryption and will happily send everything (including your user-name and password when you login) in plain text over the network.)